# Java: using the values read from the user

Tags: java

I have an array of dice that are apart of a larger program. (This section of code is in my main)

```
int[] Dice = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
      System.out.println("Die 1: " + Dice[0]);
      System.out.println("Die 2: " + Dice[1]);
      System.out.println("Die 3: " + Dice[2]);
      System.out.println("Die 4: " + Dice[3]);
      System.out.println("Die 5: " + Dice[4]);
```

I am trying to get user input so the user can chose how many dice they would like to roll with.(This section of code is from my configuration class)

```
String file = "yahtzeeConfig.txt";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //configures number of dice in hand
        System.out.println("Enter the number of dice you would like in your hand (1-5): ");
        int hand = scan.nextInt();
```

Super basic and kind of embarrassing to ask, but how would I use the values read from the user to change the amount of dice for each roll??

Comment: why are you filling the Dice array with 0 values explicitly if you define the size int [] Dice = new int[5]; java will fill the array with 0 automatically

Comment: That depends on how you roll the dice.  You haven't shown us that code.  One piece of advice though: Entering the number of dice to retain doesn't give the player any control over *which* dice are retained, as is standard in Yahtzee.  The player is usually able to select, say, the first, third, and fourth die, not just "I want any 3 dice."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach:

Once the user inputs the number of dice they want, we create a new int array, the size being the variable `hand`.

```
int hand = scan.nextInt();
int[] dices = new int[hand];
```

We then generate random values to store into the array like so:

```
Random random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < hand; i++){
    dices[i] = random.nextInt(6)+1; //<-- generates random number between 0-6
}
```

And voilà! Your `dices` array is now populated with randomly generated numbers between 1 and 6.

---

This is more efficient that generating 5 random numbers because assuming the user enters 1, you won't waste time calculating 4 extra random numbers which have no purpose.